# Missing DLL when trying to link Linqpad to my EF context

Tags: entity-framework, linqpad

I'm trying to use Linqpad to read from my EF classes. We are using EF 3.1 due to compatibility issues to the rest of the solution.

In Lingpad version 5 and higher it will only link to "Entity Framework (DbContext V4/V5/V6).
So now I'm trying Linqpad 4, but the error is the same as with Linqpad 5.

It complains that Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces DLL cannot be found. I have removed and added the Bcl DLL but still it complains.

Any other suggestions?

[image]

From csproj file:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.7.0.0\lib\net462\Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
```

Comment: I must admit I am confused about all the EF versions, but isn't EF 3.1 Entity Framework **Core**? If so, did you try LinqPad 7 which says it supports using your own assembly based on Entity Framework Core (3.x -> 7.x)?

Comment: Dunno about the versions, but my EF project is on Framework 4.8 due to compatibility to other projects in the solution. And Linqpad 7 can work with EF assemblies that are still on Framework.

Comment: Above comment should read; "And Linqpad 7 cannot work with EF assemblies that are still on this Framework. When selecting my assembly it tells me that I need to select an assembly that targetd .Net 7/6/5 or Core.

Comment: EF-core 3.1 is a later version than EF V4/V5/V6. It targets .net standard 2.0. Linqpad 5 doesn't offer a built-in connection for it. You have to add the EF NuGet package.

Comment: Are you referring to Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore? That has been added already.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried downloading the "Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces" NuGet package separately? You can download it from the NuGet website or use a package manager like NuGet Package Manager Console in Visual Studio.

Try `Install-Package Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces -Version 1.1.0`

You could also try finding the Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.dll and copying it to the Linqpad installation folder. The installation folder is typically located in "C:\Program Files (x86)\LINQPad4" or a similar path.

Comment: Thanks you for the suggestion. I have tried both, and sadly I still get the same error.